# How can to mock the method .exchangeToMono().toFuture()?

Tags: java

Tell me how mock the method .exchangeToMono().toFuture()
My example:

```
public class MyExample {
    private final WebClient webClient = WebClient.create();

    private CompletableFuture<Result> getValue(Request request) {
      return webClient
        .post().uri(request.getRequiredParameter(API_URL_PARAM))
        .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .bodyValue(request)
        .acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        .exchangeToMono(rs -> Mono.just(rs.mutate().build()))
        .toFuture()
   }}
```

My test but it is not finished I do not understand how to create a mock on
.exchangeToMono(rs -> Mono.just(rs.mutate().build())).toFuture()

```
public class MyTest {

@Mock
private WebClient webClient;

@Mock
private WebClient.RequestBodyUriSpec requestBodyUriSpecMock;

@Mock
private WebClient.RequestBodySpec requestBodySpecMock;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Mock
private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;

@Mock
private CompletableFuture<ClientResponse> responseFuture;

@Mock
private Mono<ClientResponse> clientResponseMono;

@Mock
private WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock;

@Before
public void setUp() {

    when(webClient.post()).thenReturn(requestBodyUriSpecMock);
    when(requestBodySpecMock.header(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
    when(requestBodySpecMock.acceptCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
    when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(ClientResponse.class)).thenReturn(clientResponseMono);
}

@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
    // given
    String responseBody = "{name: 'TEST'}";

    when(requestBodyUriSpecMock.uri(API_URL_VALUE)).thenReturn(requestBodySpecMock);
    when(requestBodySpecMock.bodyValue(responseBody)).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
    //when(clientResponseMono.block().statusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
    //when(responseFuture.toCompletableFuture()).thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(responseSpecMock));}
```

how to complete a test for a method?